# change just the date portion of a sql record

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Using SQL (Azure Sql)
I have a number of records that contain datetime values such as:
3/16/19 9:25 AM
3/16/19 10:15 AM

I need these to all be todays date but retain their time portion.

I am a C# programmer so my SQL is a bit rusty.

So pseudo code would be something like (asuming requested_delivery_date is the field I need updated.

update set requested_delivery_date = requested_delivery_date.dateadd(7 days)

so anything after this that had a date of 3/20/19 9:30 am would now be 3/27/19 9:30 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple `UPDATE` statement that updates all rows of `YourTable`.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET requested_delivery_date = 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, requested_delivery_date, GETDATE()), requested_delivery_date)
;
```

If you want to add a constant number of days, then the query is even simpler:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET requested_delivery_date = 
    DATEADD(DAY, 7, requested_delivery_date)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`:

```
DECLARE @Date As datetime = '2019-03-01T15:32:44'

SELECT  @Date As Source,
        GETDATE() As Today,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, GETDATE()), @Date) As Result
```

Result:

```
Source                  Today                   Result
2019-03-01 15:32:44     2019-03-28 08:27:29     2019-03-28 15:32:44
```

To update the column in the table you simply need to write an update statement:

```
update TableName
set requested_delivery_date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, requested_delivery_date , GETDATE()), requested_delivery_date)
-- add a where clause to only update some of the records
```

Comment: thank you....my question is how do I update the current records?
I can hard code the date even, they all have the same date (3/16) just different times.

Comment: Something like:
update set requested_delivery_date = requested_delivery_date.adddays(7)
But with SQL code.

Comment: The manipulation on the date stays the same, you only change the `select` to an `update` - I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you Zohar -- I had already accepted a answer, but I do appreciate your time.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and successfully. This is my table.

```
startTime   endTime
2019-03-28 15:55:10.690 2019-01-01 09:00:00.000
```

My SQL statement:

```
UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[deom1] SET [endTime]=DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [endTime], GETDATE()), [endTime])
```

And this the result:

```
startTime   endTime
2019-03-28 15:55:10.690 2019-03-28 09:00:00.000
```

For more details, please see [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you Leon -- Vladimir's answer happened to be exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate your time and answer.